# How can I add a custom tileset as a mapbox.js layer?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I am using mapbox.js to show a map on my site with different layers, however I can't manage to make my custom tileset load as a layer. It fails when trying to load in _setTileJSON()

Here's my js code:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', null, { zoomControl: false });
var layer1 = L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.outdoors');
layer1.setZIndex(1).addTo(map);
```

This one works like a charm, however when I use my custom tileset id instead of `'mapbox.outdoors'` I get the error `tile_layer.js:49 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null`. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Cristina

Comment: I have managed to user a raster based tileset, this must be the reason as the other ones I had tried were all vector.

Comment: As explained in my answer bellow mapbox.js works with raster tilesets. You can use mapbox-gl-js for vector tiles. If you find my answer useful, you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to display a [vector tileset](https://www.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/) with [mapbox.js.](https://www.mapbox.com/help/#mapbox.js) Mapbox.js supports [raster tilesets](https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-tileset/).

To display vector tilesets - use [mapbox-gl-js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/examples/) instead. Here is a basic example: [Custom style example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-style-id/)

Alternatively, you can use [Mapbox Studio Classic](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio-classic/) or Tilemill (which are no longer actively developed) to generate raster tilesets from your data and upload the generated `.mbtiles` to Mapbox for use with mapbox.js.